# Verifying the implementation of Multihead Attention in Transformer

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, keras, tensorflow, transformer

I have implemented the `MultiAttention head` in `Transformers`. There are so many implementations around so its confusing. Can someone please verify if my implementation is correct:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def scaled_dot_product(q,k,v):
    
    #calculates Q . K(transpose)
    qkt = tf.matmul(q,k,transpose_b=True)
    #caculates scaling factor
    dk = tf.math.sqrt(tf.cast(q.shape[-1],dtype=tf.float32))
    scaled_qkt = qkt/dk
    softmax = tf.nn.softmax(scaled_qkt,axis=-1)
    
    z = tf.matmul(softmax,v)
    #shape: (m,Tx,depth), same shape as q,k,v
    return z

class MultiAttention(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    
    def __init__(self,d_model,num_of_heads):
        
        super(MultiAttention,self).__init__()
        self.d_model = d_model
        self.num_of_heads = num_of_heads
        self.depth = d_model//num_of_heads
        self.wq = [tf.keras.layers.Dense(self.depth) for i in range(num_of_heads)]
        self.wk = [tf.keras.layers.Dense(self.depth) for i in range(num_of_heads)]
        self.wv = [tf.keras.layers.Dense(self.depth) for i in range(num_of_heads)]
        self.wo = tf.keras.layers.Dense(d_model)
        
    def call(self,x):
        
        multi_attn = []
        for i in range(self.num_of_heads):
            Q = self.wq[i](x)
            K = self.wk[i](x)
            V = self.wv[i](x)
            multi_attn.append(scaled_dot_product(Q,K,V))
            
        multi_head = tf.concat(multi_attn,axis=-1)
        multi_head_attention = self.wo(multi_head)
        return multi_head_attention

#Calling the attention 
multi = MultiAttention(d_model=512,num_of_heads=8)
m = 5; sequence_length = 4; word_embedding_dim = 512
sample_ip = tf.constant(tf.random.normal(shape=(m,sequence_length,word_embedding_dim)))
attn =multi(sample_ip)
#shape of op (attn): (5,4,512)
```

Comment: Why don't you validate that your output is the same as one of the official implementation? e.g. [tensorflow's](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/MultiHeadAttention), or [pytorch's](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.MultiheadAttention.html)

Comment: @noe I thought of that, but the matrix initialized can have different weights and it will  cause diff op values , so i checked just the OP shape, which was correct. But wanted to confirm if the logic was correct too.